# Tab delimited data in excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to build a tab delimited string and insert it in cell "A1". For some reason, it does not identify the tab delimiter. Here is my code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B11")), Chr(9))
```

I even tried the "vbTab" instead of "Chr(9)" but I still see no tabs in the string. Its inserting a string without any deliminator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The tabs are there but are not being displayed.  Try

```
Dim stg As String
Dim pos As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                        transpose(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B11")), Chr(9))

stg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

For pos = 1 To Len(stg)
  Debug.Print Asc(Mid(stg, pos, 1)) & " ";
Next
Debug.Print
```

The Immediate Window will shows the ASCII values of your strings spearated by nines.

Answer (score 1):

Excel cannot visually display tabs within a cell.

As far as Excel is concerned, tab means to move to the next cell. If you copy a string that has a tab in it and paste the result into Excel, it will put the text before the tab in your selected cell and the text after the tab in the next cell.

If you just need the tab to be there then you can rest assured that it is. If you want it to display visually then modify your question to explain what you are trying to do.